# VBA Code to formulate an entry cell if the value selected from a Data Validation list meets a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some assistance with VBA Code.  See below what my spreadsheet looks like but essentially it works like this:

1. The spreadsheet is all about entering budgets and capturing the spend
2. Column A is a Data Validation list which is the list of items that I have budgets for.  In this example, my list includes Apples, Oranges, Pears and Bananas
3. For each item selected, the user enters their allocated budget into Column B (Budget) and the Spend/Remaining columns are formulated.  So Column B is an ENTRY column

The issue I have is if the user selects Bananas, there is no budget required so I want to formulate Column B (the Budget column which is an ENTRY column) to automatically read $ 0.00.  This would then indicate to the user that there is no budget required.

Any help would be appreciated

```
Fruit    Budget     Spend   Remaining
APPLES   $100.00    $-       $100.00 
ORANGES  $150.00    $-       $150.00 
PEARS    $200.00    $-       $200.00 
BANANAS         $-       $-
```

Comment: Hey mdlpjr, are you still around and looking for a valid answer to your question?  If you are, please reply here and I'll try to help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that any VBA code is required for the Budget Column, Since a simple IF Formula can solve the issue.

You use this Formula for the Budget Column.

```
=IF(A2="Apple",100,IF(A2="Orange",150,IF(A2="Banana",0,IF(A2="Pear",120,"No Budget"))))
```

**NB:** *When you select Banana, Formula will put 0, and since the Spend Column
has other Formula, will take care the next step.*

*Also, **"No Budget"** will appear in Entry Column if neither of the names will in column A, you may replace it with BLANK SPACE too*

*Now about the Spend column* (Column C). It needs the below written Formula to Calculate further on the basis of Fruit name in Column A and budget value in Column B.

```
=IF(AND(A2="Apple",B2>0),B2+100,IF(AND(A2="Orange",B2>0),B2+150,IF(AND(A2="Pear",B2>0),B247+120,"No Budget")))
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Column B is actually an entry column.  The user enters the budget so in that example, when the user selects Apples, they then enter the $100 into Column B.

Comment: So if Column B is an entry column and the user selects Bananas, he doesn't need to enter a budget.  I want a VBA code to prepopulate Column B if Bananas is selected from Column A.  If any other fruit is selected, the user must enter their budget into Column B themselves